# Vertical-Alignment on Image and Text in Span

Tags: html, css

I have a text and image vertically aligned perfectly.

[image: Screenshot 1]

(Question/Issue) But I would like to put another line under it, like so...

[image: Screenshot 2]

I've tried putting a `<br\>` in the span but the text then goes directly under the image.

Here's the code for the first vertical alignment.

```
<img src="/" class="circular" style="vertical-align:middle;">
<span class="text">Text</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `line-height` on text if you know image's height.

See this snippet:

```css
.img {
    float: left;
}
.txt {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 0 5px 10px;
}
.txt-line {
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
    <div class="txt">
        <div class="txt-line">Title</div>
        <div class="txt-line">Description</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Consider using em as unit, and not px, if you ever change your font-size you will have to update your line-height as well.